# How can I change the color of the active button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

So I am trying to basically change the button that is currently actives color. I have tried to create a css class called "activePage" and add it to whichever button is clicked on. But that has not worked.

So basically if you click the "projects" button it should change the color of that button to red, and if you click the "about" button it should change that button to red and change the "projects" button back to its original color.

```js
function homeTransition()
    {   
        $(this).toggleClass('activePage');
        
        if(document.getElementById("aboutContent").className.indexOf("slideInLeft") !== -1){
        document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = " animated slideOutLeft";
        }
        if(document.getElementById("projectsContent").className.indexOf("slideInLeft") !== -1){
        document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = " animated slideOutLeft";
        }
        if(document.getElementById("contactContent").className.indexOf("slideInLeft") !== -1){
        document.getElementById("contactContent").className = " animated slideOutLeft";
        }
        document.getElementById("astronaut").className = " animated fadeIn";
    }

function aboutTransition()
    {   
        document.getElementById("astronaut").className = " animated fadeOut";
        document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = "activePage animated slideInLeft";
        
        document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = " animated fadeOutLeft";
        document.getElementById("contactContent").className = " animated fadeOutLeft";
    }

function projectsTransition()
    {   
        $(this).toggleClass('activePage');
        
        document.getElementById("astronaut").className = " animated fadeOut";
        document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = "activePage animated slideInLeft";
        
        document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = " animated fadeOutLeft";
        document.getElementById("contactContent").className = " animated fadeOutLeft";
    }

function contactTransition()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('activePage');
        
        document.getElementById("astronaut").className = " animated fadeOut";
        document.getElementById("contactContent").className = "activePage animated slideInLeft";
        
        document.getElementById("aboutContent").className = " animated fadeOutLeft";
        document.getElementById("projectsContent").className = " animated fadeOutLeft";
    }

//Menu
function expand(){
  $(this).toggleClass("on");
  $(".menu").toggleClass("active");
};
$(".button").on('click', expand);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #ccc;
  z-index: -100;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#aboutContent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 250ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  background-color: black;
  z-index: -1;
}

#projectsContent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 250ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  background-color: black;
  z-index: -1;
}

#contactContent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 250ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  background-color: black;
  z-index: -1;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(38, 139, 190, 0.84);
  width: 18%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 250ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000000;
}

.active {
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

.activePage {
    color: red;
}

h1 {
  margin-top:60%;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  cursor: default;
}

ul {
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  font-size:16px;
}

li {
  padding:10px 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:10px 15px;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:'Lato';
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

a:hover {
  color: #0dffec;
}

.content {
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
}

.button {
  width:20px;
  height:40px;
  margin:24% 36%;
  padding: 14px;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.line {
 width: 40px;
 height: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
 transition: transform 0.3s ease, background 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease, top 0.3s ease;
}

.line.first {
  transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(22px) rotate(-90deg);
}

.line.second {
  transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(19px) rotate(0deg);
}

.button.on .line.top {
 transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(20px) rotate(45deg);
}

.button.on .line.bottom {
 transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(17px)rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Home</title>
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Play|Raleway|Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
</head> 
<body>
    
    <img id="astronaut" src="images/astronaut.png">
    
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="menu">
      
    <h1>Title</h1>
      
    <ul>
       <div id="home" onclick="homeTransition()" class="noselect"><li><a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> home</a></li></div>
       <div id="about" onclick="aboutTransition()" class="noselect"><li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> about</a></li></div>
       <div id="projects" onclick="projectsTransition()" class="noselect"><li><a href="#projects"><i class="fa fa-code"></i> projects</a></li></div>
       <div id="contact" onclick="contactTransition()" class="noselect"><li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> contact</a></li></div>
    </ul>
  </div>
    
  <div class="content animated fadeInDown">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="line first top"></div>
      <div class="line second bottom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
    
    
    <div id="aboutContent">
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="projectsContent">
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="contactContent">
    
    </div>
    
</div>
    
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/transition.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/background.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Active means currently being clicked down... that usually goes by so quickly you won't see the change. Maybe you want to change the color of the button with Focus.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that! I meant when the page is active. So if the "about" page is currently active then the "about" buttons color should be changed to red.

Comment: Your functions are out of jQuery's scope. I'm writing up the answer.

Comment: Oh my lord, the quality of that code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your click functions are out of jQuery's scope.

I clipped out irrelevant code, so don't just copy and paste.

I change the HTML so it does not use onClick, and the binding happens inside jQuery's ready function instead. In addition, I modified the CSS to target the anchor tage which is actually responsible for the text style.

See the refactoring to your snippet I did below:

```js
//Menu

$(function() {
  function expand() {
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
    $(".menu").toggleClass("active");
  };

  $('.noselect').click(function() {
    $('.noselect').removeClass('activePage');
    $(this).toggleClass('activePage');
  });

  $(".button").on('click', expand);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #ccc;
  z-index: -100;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#aboutContent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 250ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  background-color: black;
  z-index: -1;
}

#projectsContent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 250ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  background-color: black;
  z-index: -1;
}

#contactContent {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 250ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  background-color: black;
  z-index: -1;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(38, 139, 190, 0.84);
  width: 18%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 250ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(-100%);
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000000;
}

.active {
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
  transform: translateZ(0) translateX(0);
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

.activePage {
  color: red;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 60%;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  cursor: default;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

li {
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

a:hover {
  color: #0dffec;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 24% 36%;
  padding: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.line {
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, background 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease, top 0.3s ease;
}

.line.first {
  transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(22px) rotate(-90deg);
}

.line.second {
  transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(19px) rotate(0deg);
}

.button.on .line.top {
  transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(20px) rotate(45deg);
}

.button.on .line.bottom {
  transform: translateX(-10px) translateY(17px)rotate(-45deg);
}

.activePage a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Home</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Play|Raleway|Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
</head>

<body>

  <img id="astronaut" src="images/astronaut.png">

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="menu">

      <h1>Title</h1>

      <ul>
        <div id="home" class="noselect">
          <li><a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> home</a></li>
        </div>
        <div id="about" class="noselect">
          <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> about</a></li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="content animated fadeInDown">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="line first top"></div>
        <div class="line second bottom"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="aboutContent"></div>
    <div id="projectsContent"></div>
    <div id="contactContent"></div>

  </div>

  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/transition.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/background.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This kind of works, but it doesn't change the color back to the original color when you click on a different button. Also when you click the button the page no longer slides out. I think it doesnt slide the page out cause it no longer is calling the function that makes the page slide out. Since you removed the onClick.

Comment: It doesn't kind of work...it completely works. I was assuming you could take it from there, but I will add the missing code eg toggleClass() or removeClass() when you click another link.

Comment: OK, I updated the snippet a bit. Please take a look and let me know if you have any issues. If it works, please accept this answer. The main change was on `$('.noselect').click()`

Comment: How are the transition functions for the page supposed to work without the onClick in html?

Comment: `$('.noselect').click()` is how jQuery can listen for the click event. Review the [jQuery documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

There's an 'active' property in CSS that allows you to change color and other characteristics of your elements.

Example:

```
button:active{
    background:olive;
}

button:focus{
    background:olive;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: His javascript logic is itself wrong. He have taken care of adding proper classes but it's just that he is targeting wrong item.

Answer (score 0):

'this' variable inside homeTransition and all other functions referring to window object.

You can fix the code by:

Changing onclick function call in HTML to:

```
<div id="home" onclick="homeTransition(event)"
```

And by adding event arguement in js file:

```
function homeTransition(event) {   
    $(event.target).toggleClass('activePage');
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.active, .btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDIV">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn active">2</button>
  <button class="btn">3</button>
  <button class="btn">4</button>
  <button class="btn">5</button>
</div>

<script>
// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  this.className += " active";
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain why your code would solve the problem.